# Resampling a number of rows 1000 times and calculate de variance

Tags: r, dplyr, resampling

I want to select 3 random rows per group for one especific variable. I want to run 1000 times. Then I want to calculate the mean, the variance and the mean's confidence intervals of these 1000 resamplings (inside each group).

In the example below: I have different groups in the last column. I want to run the resampling with the 3 random rows and calculate mean, IC and variance (for the variable1 column) inside each group.

In the end I want to have a object with the mean, the ICs and the variance for each of the groups, for variable1.

```
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(200,mean=3), nrow= 100, ncol=2)
x2 <- c(replicate(5, "AA"),replicate(15, "BB"),replicate(15, "CC"),
        replicate(10, "DD"),replicate(10, "EE"),replicate(10, "FF"),
        replicate(10, "GG"),replicate(5, "HH"),replicate(5, "II"),
        replicate(15, "JJ"))
df <- data.frame(cbind(x1,x2))
colnames(df) <- c("variable1", "variable2","group")
```

I tried to create a function to run this, but I was not successful.

```
resem <- function (x){
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    # Randomly select three rows
    sampled_rows <- x[sample(nrow(x), size = 3, replace = T), ]
    
    # Calculate the variance of the selected rows
    variance <- var(sampled_rows) 
    data.frame(variance)
  }
}
    
# Runing the function

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(resem(.$variable1))
```

Any idea, please?

Editing. I thought of something like this to calculate the confidence intervals:

```
norm.interval <- function(df$variable1,variance = var(df$variable1), conf.level = 0.95) {
  z = qnorm((1 - conf.level)/2, lower.tail = FALSE)
  xbar = mean(df$variable1)
  sdx = sqrt(variance/length(df$variable1))
  c(xbar - z * sdx, xbar + z * sdx)
}
```

Comment: Since you're using dplyr, what about `sample_n` after grouping?

Comment: how do you want to calculate IC?

Comment: @I_O I never used the `sample_n` I will check how it works. Thanks!!

Comment: @user12256545 I'm note sure, but I added something that I think is the way it in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? The function below computes the means and variances of 3 rows only, not the CI's, 1000 per group.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

set.seed(2023)
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(200,mean=3), nrow= 100, ncol=2)
x2 <- c(replicate(5, "AA"),replicate(15, "BB"),replicate(15, "CC"),
        replicate(10, "DD"),replicate(10, "EE"),replicate(10, "FF"),
        replicate(10, "GG"),replicate(5, "HH"),replicate(5, "II"),
        replicate(15, "JJ"))
df <- cbind.data.frame(x1, x2)
colnames(df) <- c("variable1", "variable2","group")

resem <- function (x, R = 1000L){
  out <- vector("list", R)
  for (i in seq.int(R)) {
    # Randomly select three rows
    sampled_rows <- x[sample(NROW(x), size = 3, replace = TRUE)]
    
    # Calculate the variance of the selected rows
    variance <- var(sampled_rows)
    out[[i]] <- data.frame(mean = mean(sampled_rows), variance)
  }
  do.call(rbind, out)
}

# Running the function

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(resem(.$variable1))
#> # A tibble: 10,000 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [10]
#>    group  mean variance
#>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 AA     1.84  0.410  
#>  2 AA     1.69  0.951  
#>  3 AA     1.99  0.714  
#>  4 AA     2.66  0.0667 
#>  5 AA     2.58  0.242  
#>  6 AA     2.88  0.00349
#>  7 AA     2.32  0.269  
#>  8 AA     2.55  0.212  
#>  9 AA     1.95  0.514  
#> 10 AA     2.40  0.160  
#> # ℹ 9,990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Another function, returning one row per group, is the following.

```r
resem <- function (x, R = 1000L){
  out <- vector("list", R)
  for (i in seq.int(R)) {
    # Randomly select three rows
    sampled_rows <- x[sample(NROW(x), size = 3, replace = TRUE)]
    
    # Calculate the variance of the selected rows
    variance <- var(sampled_rows)
    out[[i]] <- cbind(mean = mean(sampled_rows), variance)
  }
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  colMeans(out) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
}

# Runing the function

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(resem(.$variable1))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#> # Groups:   group [10]
#>    group  mean variance
#>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 AA     2.23    0.428
#>  2 BB     3.29    0.381
#>  3 CC     3.05    1.35 
#>  4 DD     3.34    0.219
#>  5 EE     3.73    0.873
#>  6 FF     2.96    1.71 
#>  7 GG     2.95    0.701
#>  8 HH     2.65    0.172
#>  9 II     3.49    0.425
#> 10 JJ     2.68    1.29
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: that is nice. Thanks! So, in the first code the line `out[[i]] <- data.frame(mean = mean(sampled_rows), variance)` the mean that is calculating is the mean of the three selected rows per group, right?
The first option works better for me, since after that I want to know how many times the variance was higher than a given value in each group... thanks again!!

Comment: @Pam *"the mean that is calculating is the mean of the three selected rows per group, right?"* Yes, that's it.